# How to convert a tensor scalar to a tensor list without detach it

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a `tensor.long` scalar named x. how can I make a list of tensor `tensor[(x.detached().numpy())]` without converting x to numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add another dimension (by converting to a `list`, you'd have an iterable container/wrapper like a dimensional tensor; unless you want any `list`-specific operations, most of the time you want to stick to a `tensor` object for further processing).

To add a dim (making the tensor 1-D), you can use `unsqueeze`:

```
x.unsqueeze(dim=0)
```

`view`/`reshape`/index-ing can be used as well:

```
x.view(-1)
x.reshape(-1)
x[None]
```